# SCHED_FIFO + sched_setaffinity = console not work?

Tags: linux, multithreading

PS. It's actually a homework problem.

I have a program. The main thread creates two child threads. All threads are specified to `SCHED_FIFO` class. Also, I use `sched_setaffinity` to make sure that threads are really FIFO. (Otherwise the two threads run on different cores and thus look interleaved) However, the output does not appear to be one line per second. All lines are printed at the end of execution. How can I make the lines printed each second?

Source code: https://gist.github.com/yan12125/b15b7ded2184aad2fb37

Compiled with: `gcc rts2015.c -pthread`

Run with: `sudo ./a.out SCHED_FIFO`

Tested on: Arch Linux x86_64, kernel 4.3, Intel i5 4 cores

Some other observations:

- stdin does not work, either.
- All other applications run as usual
- If I run `strace -fp <PID>`, then the output is printed line by line, one line per second. That's what I expected.
- If I turn all CPUs except the first one off via `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/online` and remove the `sched_setaffinity` call, everything works as expected.

The third phenomenon is surprising to me. AFAIK `strace` uses `ptrace()`. Why `ptrace()` it makes everything OK?